# Is there a way in Accord.NET to match SURF features?

Tags: accord.net

I have detected features like this:

```
Grayscale GS = new Grayscale(10, 10, 10);
GS.Apply(Image1);
GS.Apply(Image2);
List<SpeededUpRobustFeaturePoint> Image1Features;
List<SpeededUpRobustFeaturePoint> Image2Features;
Image1Features = Detector.Transform(Image1).ToList();
Image2Features = Detector.Transform(Image2).ToList();
```

But how do I match them? Do I write my own implementation of desired metric or I am missing some Accord.NET functionality for featrue matching?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Sample-applications#image-stitching-surf) of image stitching using SURF features, [they are using](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/master/Samples/Imaging/Panorama%20(SURF)/MainForm.cs#L94)  *KNearestNeighborMatching*.